# Multi-User Server ; Basic Authentication ; User 1 Can Access User 2s Folder After Logging In To His Own and Backtracking

Tags: php, apache-2.4, .htaccess, http-basic-authentication

I have an Apache 2.4 server running with PHP and MySQL included. I have pages that are restricted (or are supposed to be) to certain users only. Each user has their own restricted page and must supply a username and password to access it. Inside the homepage is a button that redirects them to the `index.html` page using `<a href="../index.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Return To Landing</button></a>`.

My issue comes up when a user authenticates to their homepage, and then navigates back to the index where users select their page. After logging in and backtracking back to the `index.html` page, they can jump onto other users secure pages without providing a username and password for it.

Here's what I have for the `.htaccess` files for each users folder, where their homepage resides:

```
AuthUserFile C:/Server/data/htdocs/creds/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Password Required To Proceed"
AuthType Basic

<Limit GET POST>
require valid-user
require user [username]
</Limit>

<Files .htaccess>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

php_value memory_limit 2048M
php_value post_max_size 6250M
php_value upload_max_filesize 6144M
php_value max_input_time 600
php_value max_execution_time 600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> require valid-user
> require user [username]
> ```

`require valid-user` will allow *any* valid user. You shouldn't be using this together with `require user ...` (which allows just that specific user).

Comment: Understood. I was under the impression the `require valid-user` acted as an extra bit of verification to check that the user supplied valid credentials.